# WPF Validation of Textbox, what should the binding look like?

Tags: .net, wpf, validation, xaml, textbox

I'm trying to validate a textbox in WPF. I found some examples on the internet and I've put together some things. But right now it just validates everything as if it was wrong. I was told it's my binding, as I'm not sure what to bind to what I've come here for some clarification :)

Here's my validator:

```cs
class TextRangeValidator : ValidationRule
    {
        private int _minimumLength = 0;
        private int _maximumLength = 0;
        private string _errorMessage;

        public int MinimumLength
        {
            get { return _minimumLength; }
            set { _minimumLength = value; }
        }

        public int MaximumLength
        {
            get { return _maximumLength; }
            set { _maximumLength = value; }
        }

        public string ErrorMessage
        {
            get { return _errorMessage; }
            set { _errorMessage = value; }
        }

        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value,
            CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            ValidationResult result = new ValidationResult(true, null);
            string inputString = (string)value.ToString();
            if (inputString.Length < this.MinimumLength ||
                (
                 inputString.Length > this.MaximumLength))
            {
                result = new ValidationResult(false, this.ErrorMessage);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Here's my xaml code:

```
<TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="118,60,0,0" Name="CreateUserCPRTextbox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" >
    <TextBox.Text >
        <Binding Path="Name" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" ValidatesOnDataErrors="true">
            <Binding.ValidationRules  >
                <validators:TextRangeValidator
                    ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"
                    MinimumLength="10"
                    MaximumLength="10"
                    ErrorMessage="CPR nummer ikke gyldigt" />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Right now my binding property is just named name, I've tried to make it bind to the CreateUserCPRTextbox.Text but it doesn't work. How does this work?

Comment: I've also tried making a property in the xaml.cs file and binding the textbox to it. that did not help either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to bind it to a source and path, for example the following simple object:

```
public  class Class1
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The object can be created by adding it to the window its resource collection.
The source binds to the object and the path to its property [Name], which in this example is "0123456789".

```
<Window.Resources>
    <validators:Class1 x:Key="class1" Name="0123456789" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Lastly, you have to bind its source to this resource by Source={StaticResource class1}

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="118,60,0,0" Name="CreateUserCPRTextbox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" >
        <TextBox.Text >
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource class1}" Path="Name" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" ValidatesOnDataErrors="true">
                <Binding.ValidationRules  >
                    <validators:TextRangeValidator ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" MinimumLength="10" MaximumLength="10" ErrorMessage="CPR nummer ikke gyldigt" />
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

Next, you can play some with the validated textbox.

Comment: So i have to make a new c# class just for having a property that the Textbox can bind to? - So I could have a class for all the properties I want to validate?

Comment: You just made my day, I've been having trouble with this for so long. Now I'm just wondering. Why couldn't I just not make the path Textbox.text? Isn't that a property aswell?

Comment: Normally, you want to bind the textbox.text to something that can be validated, not to itself. It just makes no sense. The input has to go somewhere in the application logic. Of course, you can set it to any (data)source.